# Como definir o email como nome de usuario no django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

Tenho o seguinte código para criar um User personalizado:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin,UserManager

class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField('Nome de Usuário',max_length=30,unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('E-mail',unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Nome',max_length=100,blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Está Ativo?',blank=True,default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('É da Equipe?',blank=True,default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('Data de Entrada',auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return str(self)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Usuário'
verbose_name_plural = 'Usuários'
```

Acredito que o campo "USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'" defina qual sera o nome do usuário, quando eu mudo o valor para email (nome do meu campo de email) quando vou criar um super usuário, o User agora e o email mas logo depois de digitar a senha pela segunda vez um erro ocorre  com referencia ao username.

Alguém pode me informar a forma correta de se fazer isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Você deve escrever um *custom authentication backend*. Algo como isso vai funcionar:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class EmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if getattr(user, 'is_active', False) and  user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None
```

Em seguida, configure esse *authentication backend* como o seu back-end de autenticação no seu *settings*:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['path.to.auth.module.EmailBackend']
```